# I was creating this Alarm app in flutter, but have no idea how can I implement this custom time picker any idea?

Tags: flutter

Any packages i could use or any way I could implement it?
First i thpught to use list view but wasn't able to do from it.
Other packages like circular motion wasn't able to get the desired result
Pls help really don't know how to even begin
Sorry for any mistakes new to stack overflow

Alarm app Image

[image: Alarm app Image]

Comment: I think you can look into [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/50554a116698f03a862a356c38b75eb3). Also for startup you can check if `CupertinoPicker` does work you.